# Boost serialization compiling issue

Tags: c++, xml, serialization, boost, xml-serialization

I am using boost serialization on windows, and I wanted to test my code on linux (ubuntu) and unfortunately it does not compile.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>


#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>


class MyClass
{
  public:
    int something;
    MyClass();

    template<class archive> void serialize(archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
      using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
      ar & make_nvp("something", something);
    }


};



MyClass::MyClass()
  : something(0)
{
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  std::cout << "Hello";
  MyClass obj();

  std::string path = "here.xml";

  std::ifstream ifs(path.c_str());
  if (ifs.good())
  {
    boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("obj", obj);

    ifs.close();
    return true;
  }
  else
    return false;

}
```

Here is my compile line:

```
g++ test.cpp -lboost-serialization
```

And here is what I get:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/basic_xml_iarchive.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp:24,
                 from test.cpp:6:
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp: In function ‘void boost::archive::load(Archive&, const T&) [with Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive, T = MyClass()]’:
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:61:   instantiated from ‘void boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<Archive>::load_override(T&, int) [with T = MyClass(), Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/basic_xml_iarchive.hpp:81:   instantiated from ‘void boost::archive::basic_xml_iarchive<Archive>::load_override(const boost::serialization::nvp<T>&, int) [with T = MyClass(), Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp:75:   instantiated from ‘void boost::archive::xml_iarchive_impl<Archive>::load_override(T&, int) [with T = const boost::serialization::nvp<MyClass()>, Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:61:   instantiated from ‘Archive& boost::archive::detail::interface_iarchive<Archive>::operator>>(T&) [with T = const boost::serialization::nvp<MyClass()>, Archive = boost::archive::xml_iarchive]’
test.cpp:48:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:570: error: no matching function for call to ‘load_wrapper(boost::archive::xml_iarchive&, MyClass (&)(), boost::serialization::is_wrapper<MyClass()>)’
```

I am probably missing an include...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've encountered the [Most Vexing Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work). In your main method, change

```
MyClass obj();
```

to

```
MyClass obj;
```

also, on my Linux system, the link line is

```
g++ test.cpp -lboost_serialization
```

Note the underscore instead of dash, like in your example

```
g++ test.cpp -lboost-serialization
```